# Closed : Logback xml not picked by weblogic

Tags: weblogic, logback

We have externalized the logback configuration in our spring app.

- Used logback spring ext
  `compile 'org.logback-extensions:logback-ext-spring:0.1.4'`
- Added following lines in web.xml

`<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/${log-config-folder}/api/logback.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`

- Placed logback.xml in the folder mentioned in web.xml

`/usr/me/my-app/log-config
  /api
  /logback.xml`

- Added JVM argument in start up script of tomcat.

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog-config-folder=usr/me/my-app/log-config"`

- When the app is deployed in tomcat, it works perfectly fine. We are able to see the logs. When logback xml gets updated, I can see changes reflecting immediately in the app (changing LOG LEVELs)

Problem: When this same configuration is moved to weblogic, its not picking up the logback xml from external folder. JVM argument is added to weblogic start up script. I can see the JVM argument getting set.

Weblogic team came back and told they have made the weblogic setting to prioritize application classes and config.

`<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>`

Any pointers to triaging this would be really helpful.

Comment: Closing this question:

Comment: Closing this question: Issue was that my WAR was not an expanded deployment in weblogic and LogbackConfigListener option won't work. I fixed it with an alternate solution.